# Initiate Bootstrap tooltip manually

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

With bootstrap popovers, you are able to control when to hide and show them on any element

```
<span id="span">Click me</span>

<script>
$('#span').click(function(){
    $(this).popover({
        title: 'some title',
        content: 'nice popover',
        trigger: 'manual',
        placement:'top',
        html: true
    }).popover('show');
    clickedAway = false
    isVisible = true
});
$(document).click(function() {
    if(isVisible & clickedAway){
        $('#span').popover('hide')
    isVisible = clickedAway = false
    }else{
    clickedAway = true
    }
});
</script>
```

How can I accomplish the same with bootstrap tooltips?  The difference with popovers and tooltips seems to be that tooltips are initiated on DOM load and popovers can be initiated manually from an event listener.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I understand it you can call:

```
$('#id').tooltip({
    ...config...
});

$('#id').tooltip('show');
```

At any point?

Comment: I'm actually trying to call a tooltip on click, not hover, so the default usage doesn't work in this scenario.

Comment: So configure it using the `trigger` config option. Turn off `hover`. You can actually configure it to use `click` instead OR you can call `show` yourself.

Comment: Configuring it directly to use click instead of from an event listener worked like a charm. So simple, thx!

Comment: I have tooltip appearing in a read only textbox if the value is greater than 100 but if I move the mouse over, the default tooltip appears. How do I stop that?